# Save Document: "ALL FORMATS"

Tags: format, documents

When saving a document in *Writer*, does **All Formats** (in the drop-down menu) mean that when sent as an email attachment, the document will always be faithfully displayed in any format (listed in the menu) in which it is opened by the email recipient?

Comment: Open/libre office writer or something else?

Comment: No, it does not mean that.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the receiver can open the file, save it as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

No. All that "all formats" means is that the file selection dialogue will show you files of all formats rather than only that particular format.

There is no such thing as a universal file format nor a button to magically read the mind of your recipient to find out what format will suit them.